# What kind of succulent is my plant here?

Tags: identification, succulents

I got this about one and a half years ago. It used to have about 6 wider leaves lower down, but they fell off one by one over the months, and now it's grown these three cute little branches of little fleshy leaves. What kind of succulent is this? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This succulent is from the genus *Crassula*, I think species *C. rogersii*. But I am not 100% sure, the thick (swollen) round shape of the leaves makes me think that.

The most famous member of this genus *Crassula* is the Jade plant (*Crassula ovata*), it looks very similar, but the leaves are usually a bit flatter than yours.